# Why does the plane disappear and cube fall when I start the game?

Tags: game-engine

When I play the game the plane disappears and my cube falls. I've tried changing the physics but it still falls. I'm following [this tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxoyoXNFWUM) and I have problems understanding it.

Comment: Please don't put links in question titles. Use the title to describe your problem specifically, so it is easier for people to recognize if they can help you, and easier for others later to find the information if they have a similar problem. In the body of the question, please be specific about the physics settings and what you have set up. Sceenshots can be helpful.

Comment: @JacobDalton This [LINK](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Physics/Soft_Body/Collisions) might be helpful to you.

Comment: your tutorial works well, something is wrong, review the videos and repeat everything in a new blend or upload your file here for revision [0](https://youtu.be/9_oxX5Mkk0s)
[1](https://youtu.be/Pb4jNURRFlQ)
[part 1](https://youtu.be/9nWK8iX2WGM)
[part 2](https://youtu.be/LxoyoXNFWUM)
[Logic Brics step by step](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLP4ZTdOUQXB3VLp6j6WuAm4JJWxJ6F8Co)

Comment: [upload blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)